# php simple dom parser returning "Array"

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst';
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo $html->find('body');
?>
```

This has been returning "Array" on the browser when I try to ONLY get the contents of the body element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because there *may* be many elements that fit that selector, so an *array* of elements is returned. If you only want the first matching element, use `$html->find('body', 0)`. This is all described in the manual: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: this html doesn't have an iframe...are there sometimes more than one body ?? sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: @Praneet No, there should never be more than one `<body>`, **but the `find()` method doesn't know or care.** *Any* selector *may* match more than one element. That the specific selector `'body'` *should* never match more than one element is irrelevant. What should `find()` do? If there's only one match, return that one match, otherwise return an array? That'd make your code more complicated since you'd always have to check whether it returned an array or an element. So, it's always returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
echo $html->find('body', 0);
```